# Ember send action from component to context controller

Tags: ember.js

In the case below videoEnded function is successfully called, however how do I get a reference to the actual Ember component it self?

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   videoEnded: function(){
       var self = this;
       alert('how do i get a reference to the actual ember component object here ?')
    }

   didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        var options = {};
         self._soundjs = soundjs('soundOne', options, function(){
        });

         self._soundjs.on('ended',self.videoEnded);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solved my issue. `videEnded` callback was losing the components context. The following code resolved the issue, `self` passed to video ended refers to the component context which can then be used, to send actions to the context controller.

```
self._soundjs.on('ended',function() { self.videoEnded.apply(self, arguments); });
```

Credit: @teddyzeenny